# Validating a model and focus to the element if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, authentication, backbone.js

I am using Backbone Marionette - I would like to set the user name and password if that passes the model validation method.

I am highly confused with that.  Please show me a handy approach or correct me if I'm doing this wrong.

```
define(["backbone"], function(Backbone){
    var LoginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
                userName:'',
                password:''
        },
        validate:function(attr, options){
            if (!attr.userName) {
                return 'I need your userName';
              }
              if (!attr.password) {
                return 'I need your password';
              }
        },
        initialize:function(){
            this.on("invalid", function(model, error){
                console.log(model, error); // error consoles 2 times (4 times for both)
            });
        }
    });

    return LoginModel;
});
```

View.js:

```
define([
    'jQuery','underscore',
    'backbone','marionette',
    'text!./templates/loginView.html'],
    function($,_,Backbone,Marionette,template){
        "use strict";

        var LoginView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

            className:'col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4',

            template:_.template(template),

            events:{
                "submit form" : "loginSubmit"
            },

            loginSubmit:function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = Backbone.Syphon.serialize(e.target),

                validUser = this.model.set('userName',data.userName, {validate: true}),
                validPass = this.model.set('password', data.password,{validate: true});

                if(!validUser){
                    $(e.target).find('#userName').select();
                } else{
                    $(e.target).find('#userName').next(':input').select();
                }

                if(!validPass){
                    $(e.target).find('#userName').select();
                }

            }

        });

        return LoginView;
    }
);
```

This works, but I am looking for the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Backbone, however I do have a couple of comments:

- To simplify your life, check out [Marionette Forms](https://github.com/not-only-code/marionette-forms). It can handle quick validation of forms. This is an alternative to [Backbone Forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms), which is generally more demanding in terms of code needed.
- The following snippet:

  ```
  if(!validUser){
      $(e.target).find('#userName').select();
  } else{
      $(e.target).find('#userName').next(':input').select();
  }

  if(!validPass){
      $(e.target).find('#userName').select();
  }
  ```

  could simply be:

  ```
  if (validUser && validPass) {
      $(e.target).find('#userName').next(':input').select();
  } else {
      $(e.target).find('#userName').select();
  }
  ```